# How to exclude workbooks of a Sheet when converting to PDF via script

Tags: google-sheets, pdf-generation

```js
function convertSpreadsheetToPdfNonIncremental(spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName) {

  var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId ? spreadsheetId : spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetName ? spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() : null;  
  var pdfName = pdfName ? pdfName : spreadsheet.getName();
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).getParents();
  var folder = parents.hasNext() ? parents.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId is provided
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
      +  '&gid=1012506648'
      +  '&id=11NMFpk15pZ12RdXUsFRN8onueG9mhZqV57xLz_YoQY8'
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=false'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&scale=4'          //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  
  

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById('11NMFpk15pZ12RdXUsFRN8onueG9mhZqV57xLz_YoQY8');
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3:C7');
      var first = range.getCell(1, 1);
      var last = range.getCell(5,2);
      var pdfName = first.getValue() + ' Timesheet for Payroll Beginning ' + last.getDisplayValue();

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName +'.pdf');
  folder.createFile(blob);
  
}



function convertSpreadsheetToPdfIncremental(spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName) {

  var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId ? spreadsheetId : spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetName ? spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() : null;
  var pdfName = pdfName ? pdfName : spreadsheet.getName();
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).getParents();
  var folder = parents.hasNext() ? parents.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId1 is provided
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=false'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&scale=4'          //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  
       var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById('11NMFpk15pZ12RdXUsFRN8onueG9mhZqV57xLz_YoQY8');
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3:C7');
      var first = range.getCell(1, 1);
      var last = range.getCell(5,2);
      var pdfName = first.getValue() + ' Timesheet for Payroll Beginning ' + last.getDisplayValue();

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName +'.pdf');
  folder.createFile(blob);
  
}
```

I have found, and been able to figure out the script, to convert either one workbook or all workbooks to PDF but can not find instruction/tips on how to convert more than one but no all, or exclude, workbooks when converting to PDF.

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet that I want to convert all workbooks but one to PDF via script, and do not have the option of hiding the workbook that I don't want to convert.

Help please!

Comment: Share the scripts that work with one or all sheets.

Comment: These are the adapted from scripts found on this site and others:

Comment: I just tried copying and pasting at the comments section is saying it's too many characters in a reply.  I tried editing the original comment and got a message it was formatted wrong, that it needs 4 spaces indented.  Do I copy the script and then left align all the code 4 spaces indented, even if it is indented in the script?

Comment: Both scripts are in the same snippet, don't know if I posted it on here right, lol.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? If so please share as the answer